# On withdraw coinpayments error message "Transaction value exceeds per-TX limit!"

Tags: php, coin-change, coinpayments-api

I'm trying to create a withdraw with LTCT using the coinpayments api 
with this PHP code

I've tried using CreateWithdraw method and ConvertCoins

```
$amount = (float)$total; // in usd
$currency1 = 'LTCT';

$add_tx_fee = 0; // 0 receiver pays for transaction charge

$currency2 = 'USD';

$address_to_send = trim($user->coinpayments_wallet_address);

$auto_confirm = 0;

$fields = array( "amount" => $amount,
                 "currency" => $currency1,
                 "currency2" => $currency2,

// "add_tx_fee" => $add_tx_fee,

"address" => $address_to_send,

"auto_confirm" => $auto_confirm, // set to 1 withdrawal will complete without email confirmation

);

$result = $cps->CreateWithdrawal($fields);

// this doesn't work also. It throws 'Conversion not possible error message'
//$result = $cps->ConvertCoins($amount, 'BTC', $currency2, $address_to_send);
```

but I get the following error message:

> array:2 [▼
>   "error" => "Transaction value exceeds per-TX limit!"
>   "result" => []

But I was trying to get only a small amount like $5. So what's wrong?

I did some tests last week and worked just fine with conversion between ltct and dollar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, coinpayments support helped me out with this one...

it was necessary to update the daily limit of transactions...
my lack of experience with this...

[image]

now it works...

[image]